# Default lifetime in Cache Component

Tags: php, caching, symfony, symfony-components

I need configure default lifetime from cache Adapter, but something weird has been happening, the follows don't works!? :/

```
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter;

// in seconds; applied to cache items that don't define their own lifetime  
// 0 means to store the cache items indefinitely (i.e. until the files are deleted)
$cache = new FilesystemAdapter('my_namespace', 5); // <-- default lifetime 5 seconds
$latestNews = $cache->getItem('latest_news');

if (!$latestNews->isHit()) {
    $news = ['title' => '...', 'createdAt' => (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')];
    $cache->save($latestNews->set($news));
} else {
    $news = $latestNews->get();
}
```

> Reference http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_pools.html#filesystem-cache-adapter

The first time, the cached file content shows:

```
2147483647 <-- 2038-01-18 22:14:07 :/ ?
latest_news
a:2:{s:5:"title";s:3:"...";s:9:"createdAt";s:19:"2016-10-07 09:16:50";}
```

and of course this item don't expire after 5 seconds :/ (I've cleared the cache directory manually).

On the other hand, if we use `$latestNews->expiresAfter(5);` all works fine:

```
1475849350 <-- 2016-10-07 10:09:10 \o/ OK
latest_news
a:2:{s:5:"title";s:3:"...";s:9:"createdAt";s:19:"2016-10-07 10:09:05";}
```

> Reference http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_items.html#cache-item-expiration

5 seconds after the item expired correctly.

I tested that with `Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\ApcuAdapter` and occurs the same problem too.

---

**What happens with default lifetime (constructor parameter) in cache adapters ?** I missing something here :/ ?

Comment: check if  you have an older version with this bug https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/19442

Comment: Yes, that it's :) thanks @Matteo `composer update` right now!

Comment: can i post the comment as an answer so you can close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is an old issue [[Cache] Fix default lifetime being ignored](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/19442) that affect framework version prior to the 3.1

Upgrading the Symfony framework should fix it.

Comment: ... or upgrading the Cache component should fix it ;)